# Regex (Python) - How to match part of a string multiple times?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

I need a python regex matching the part of a string multiple times:

My String: `aaaa-bb-ccc-dd`
My Pattern: `([A-z]+)\-([A-z]+)`

I would like to have groups like this:
1: `aaaa-bb`
2: `bb-ccc`
3: `ccc-dd`

Does somebody have an idea on how to do this? If it does not work with regex only, a solution with a python for loop is also very welcome.

Comment: Noticed you had attempt after closing. Please do not remove attempts from questions. Reverted to original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lookahead to get overlapping matches:

```
(?=\b([A-Za-z]+-[A-Za-z]+)\b)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ndhfqm/2).

*Details*:

- `(?=` - start of a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with

  - `\b` - a word boundary
  - `([A-Za-z]+-[A-Za-z]+)` - Group 1: one or more ASCII letters, `-`, one or more ASCII letters
  - `\b` - a word boundary
- `)` - end of the lookahead.

In Python, use it with `re.findall`:

```py
import re
text = "aaaa-bb-ccc-dd"
print( re.findall(r'(?=\b([A-Z]+-[A-Z]+)\b)', text, re.I) )
# => ['aaaa-bb', 'bb-ccc', 'ccc-dd']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/EBSIUM). Note I changed `[A-Za-z]` to `[A-Z]` in the code since I made the regex matching case insensitive with the help of the `re.I` option. Make sure you are using the `r` string literal prefix or `\b` will be treated as a BACKSPACE char, `\x08`, and not a word boundary.

***Variations***

- `(?=\b([^\W\d_]+-[^\W\d_]+)\b)` - matching any Unicode letters
- `(?=(?<![^\W\d_])([^\W\d_]+-[^\W\d_]+)(?![^\W\d_]))` - matching any Unicode letters and the boundaries are any non-letters